# Streamlit : Dynamically open multiple pdfs files in different tabs

Tags: python, file-upload, tabs, streamlit

I have a Streamlit application where I can upload some pdf files and then select the files I want to work on from a select box and they will be displayed in the main panel. Now instead of displaying all the selected pdfs one after the other, I wonder if it’s possible to dynamically open every selected file in a new tab with the file name as its title. Of course, if I un-select the file, the tab should disappear.

Here's what I have tried so far, but it's not working as I want. Any suggestions ?

```
import streamlit as st
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from io import BytesIO

# Function to read PDF and return content
def read_pdf(file_path):
    # Replace with your PDF reading logic
    pdf = PdfReader(file_path)
    return pdf

# Function to display PDF content
def display_pdf(pdf):
    num_pages = pdf.page_count

    # Display navigation input for selecting a specific page
    page_number = st.number_input(
        "Enter page number", value=1, min_value=1, max_value=num_pages
    )

    # Display an image for the selected page
    image_bytes = pdf[page_number - 1].get_pixmap().tobytes()
    st.image(image_bytes, caption=f"Page {page_number} of {num_pages}")

# Main Streamlit app code
st.title("PDF Viewer App")

# Get uploaded files
selected_files = st.file_uploader("Upload PDF files", type=["pdf"], accept_multiple_files=True)

# List to store content of all pages for each file
all_files_content = []

# Dictionary to store selected file content
selected_file_content = {}

# Iterate over uploaded files
for uploaded_file in selected_files:
    file_content = uploaded_file.read()

    temp_file_path = f"./temp/{uploaded_file.name}"
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(temp_file_path), exist_ok=True)

    with open(temp_file_path, "wb") as temp_file:
        temp_file.write(file_content)

    if uploaded_file.type == "application/pdf":
        # Read PDF and store content
        pdf = read_pdf(temp_file_path)
        all_files_content.append(pdf)

        # Display PDF content
        selected_file_content[uploaded_file.name] = pdf

        # Cleanup: Remove the temporary file
        os.remove(temp_file_path)

# Create tabs dynamically for each file
with st.tabs(list(selected_file_content.keys())):
    for file_name, pdf in selected_file_content.items():
        display_pdf(pdf)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can now render PDFs in streamlit.

Install streamlit-pdf-viewer:
`pip install streamlit-pdf-viewer`

Usage:

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_pdf_viewer import pdf_viewer
        
pdf_viewer("str, path or bytes")
```

Please refer to this python package: https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-pdf-viewer/

Comment: I have now included how to use it as well !

Answer (score -3):

To begin ensure that you have installed the `PyQt5` library if its not already installed. You can do this by running the following command in your terminal;

```bash
pip install PyQt5
```

Once you have `PyQt5` installed you can proceed with creating a Python script containing the code below;

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class PDFViewer(QMainWindow);
  def __init__(self pdf_files);
    super(PDFViewer, self).__init__()

    self.setWindowTitle("PDF Viewer")

    self.tabs = QTabWidget()
    self.central_widget = QWidget()
    self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    self.open_pdfs(pdf_files)

  def open_pdfs(self, pdf_files);
    for pdf_file in pdf_files;
      pdf_view = QWebEngineView()
      pdf_view.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(pdf_file))
      self.tabs.addTab(pdf_view, 

def main(pdf_files);
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  viewer = PDFViewer(pdf_files)
  viewer.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "____";
  # Replace the list below with the paths, to your PDF files
  pdf_files =
Replace the list called `pdf_files` with the paths, to the PDF files that you would like to open.
```

Comment: I want it using Streamlit not PyQt5

Comment: Note to reviewers: [Are answers which misunderstood the question very low quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272925/are-answers-which-misunderstood-the-question-low-quality) and [Are answers that completely ignore the explicit constraints of the question very low quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401134/are-answers-that-completely-ignore-the-explicit-constraints-of-the-question-very) The correct review is "Looks OK". (Misunderstanding the question is, of course, a valid reason to downvote if it makes the answer not be useful).